# Running an animation in reverse on mouseout

Tags: jquery

After getting my hands dirty with jQuery for two weeks or so, I think it's awesome and I learned a lot but I cannot figure if there is a way to reverse animations. I am talking about some kind of toggle but for more complex animations.

For an example, check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Z6xd2/

I know I can do fadeToggle in this situations, but I am refering to more complex situations, where multiple animations take effect when you hover over a single div.

Do I have to write the code for the animation to go in reverse like this?

```
//animation
$(".box-1").on('mouseover', function(){
    $(this).find('.main-image').animate({
        'opacity': '0.2'
    });
});

//reversing the animation
$(".box-1").on('mouseout', function(){
    $(this).find('.main-image').animate({
        'opacity': '1'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about reverse animation, but you can make it nicer and easier using jQueryUI to animate class adding and removing.
Like this:

```
$(".box-1").on('mouseover', function(){
    $(this).find('.main-image').addClass('over', 500);
});

$(".box-1").on('mouseout', function(){
    $(this).find('.main-image').removeClass('over', 500);
});
```

I modified your code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Z6xd2/3/

Comment: Thanks, but I think you forgot to save the fiddle.